# Updating an object in an array based on a value in that object

Tags: arrays, database, rethinkdb

I'm trying to update an item in an array within a rethinkdb document. The document looks like this.

```
{
    "id":   "dab7ddcd-29bb-4ff2-afcb-f4bb030f74bd",
    "number":   1,
    "questions":    [
        {
            "question": "Meneer ik snap iets niet",
            "questiondid":  "839d5e49-5b50-4c61-960e-d7e1431949ef",
            "upvotes":  0,
            "userid":   111523
        },
        {
            "question": "Meneer ik snap iets niet",
            "questiondid":  "1ea57f05-f637-4758-b341-c5272538f80c",
            "upvotes":  0,
            "userid":   111523
        }
    ],
    "sha":  "1234567890jareau",
    "title":    "Test question"
}
```

In this example I'm trying to change the value of 'upvotes' to 1 in the question with the id: "1ea57f05-f637-4758-b341-c5272538f80c". How would I go about doing this dynamically, without knowing what the index of the object in the array is?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
r.table('test').get(ID).update(function(row) {
  {questions: row('questions').merge(function(q) {
    return r.branch(q('questiondid').eq(QUESTION_ID), {upvotes: 1}, {});
  })};
});
```

Comment: And what if i wanted to make the upvotes an array of users that upvoted the question, how would i then go about adding a user to that list?

Comment: Replace `{upvotes: 1}` with `{upvotes: q('upvotes').setInsert(NEW_VOTER)}`.